# Find out if a matrix is positive definite with NumPy

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy

How can I find out if a matrix is [positive definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix)?

My matrix is a NumPy matrix. I was expecting to find any related method in the NumPy library, but I didn't have any success.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can also check if all the [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) of matrix are positive. If so, the matrix is positive definite:

```
import numpy as np

def is_pos_def(x):
    return np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(x) > 0)
```

Comment: You could use np.linalg.eigvals instead, which only computes the eigenvalues. Even then, it's much slower than @NPE's approach (3x for 10x10 matrices, 40x for 1000x1000).

Comment: <pedantic>It is not true in general that all positive eigenvalues implies positive definiteness, unless you know that the matrix is symmetric (real case) or Hermitian (complex case).  For example, A = array([[1, -100],[0, 2]]) is not positive definite.  Some might include symmetric or Hermitian as part of the *definition* of "positive definite", but that is not universal.</pedantic>

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Oops, that's right, not pedantic! In fact, checking symmetry is also needed if using `np.linalg.cholesky` (it doesn't check it and may return a wrong result, as your example also shows). I wonder how checking whether a non symmetric matrix is positive definite can be done numerically...

Comment: You can do `np.all(x-x.T==0)` to check for symmetry

Comment: This is terribly inefficient! For matrices larger than about 6 or 7 rows/columns, use cholesky as pointed out by NPE below. The cholesky route feels less convenient (catching an exception etc) but it is much less wasteful.

Comment: If you're working with hermitian or symmetric matrices, use `np.linalg.eigvalsh` instead; it's a lot faster

Answer (score 97):

You could try computing Cholesky decomposition ([`numpy.linalg.cholesky`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cholesky.html)). This will raise `LinAlgError` if the matrix is not positive definite.

Comment: This should be substantially more efficient than the eigenvalue solution.

Comment: Just a note that in the positive semi-definite case, numerically speaking, one can also add a little identity to the matrix (thus shifting all eigenvalues a small amount e.g. a few times machine precision) then use the cholesky method as usual.

Comment: A quick warning: from the docs for `numpy.linalg.cholesky`: `No checking is performed to verify whether a is Hermitian or not. In addition, only the lower-triangular and diagonal elements of a are used.` In other words, if you test a non-symmetric or non-Hermitian matrix, `cholesky` may not raise a `LinAlgError` even if that matrix is not positive definite. See @DanielGarza's answer for a potential fix

Comment: @MRocklin what doy our mean with efficient? lower time complexity?

Answer (score 45):

There seems to be a small confusion in all of the answers above (at least concerning the question).

For real matrices, the tests for positive eigenvalues and  positive-leading terms in np.linalg.cholesky only applies if the matrix is symmetric. So first one needs to test if the matrix is symmetric and then apply one of those methods (positive eigenvalues or Cholesky decomposition).

For example:

```
import numpy as np

#A nonsymmetric matrix
A = np.array([[9,7],[6,14]])

#check that all eigenvalues are positive:
np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(A) > 0)

#take a 'Cholesky' decomposition:
chol_A = np.linalg.cholesky(A)
```

The matrix A is not symmetric, but the eigenvalues are positive and Numpy returns a Cholesky decomposition that is wrong. You can check that:

```
chol_A.dot(chol_A.T)
```

is different than A.

You can also check that all the python functions above would test positive for 'positive-definiteness'. This could potentially be a serious problem if you were trying to use the Cholesky decomposition to compute the inverse, since:

```
>np.linalg.inv(A)
array([[ 0.16666667, -0.08333333],
   [-0.07142857,  0.10714286]])

>np.linalg.inv(chol_A.T).dot(np.linalg.inv(chol_A))
array([[ 0.15555556, -0.06666667],
   [-0.06666667,  0.1       ]])
```

are different.

In summary, I would suggest adding a line to any of the functions above to check if the matrix is symmetric, for example:

```
def is_pos_def(A):
    if np.array_equal(A, A.T):
        try:
            np.linalg.cholesky(A)
            return True
        except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

You may want to replace np.array_equal(A, A.T) in the function above for np.allclose(A, A.T) to avoid differences that are due to floating point errors.

Comment: Nitpick: you should probably check for `numpy.linalg.LinAlgError` unless you import it with `from numpy.linalg import LinAlgError`, which isn't a thing I would want to do if I would only catch this specific exception once or twice in my code.

Comment: If working with complex matrices, this might lead to error (namely if A is complex positive definite, hence hermitian with strictly positive eigenvalues, the cholesky trick is still correct but it will not pass the first `if` statement for `np.allclose(A, A.T)`). Using `np.allclose(A, A.H)` will fix this (the OP says he is working with numpy matrix, if working with ndarray, use `A.conj().T` instead of `.H`

Answer (score 6):

To illustrate [NPE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266720/find-out-if-a-matrix-is-positive-definite-with-numpy/16266736#16266736) with some ready-to-use code:

```
import numpy as np

def is_pd(K):
    try:
        np.linalg.cholesky(K)
        return 1
    except np.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError as err:
        if 'Matrix is not positive definite' in err.message:
            return 0
        else:
            raise
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why [the solution of NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266720/find-out-if-a-matrix-is-positive-definite-with-numpy/16266736#16266736) is so underrated. It's the best way to do this. I've found [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Proof_for_positive_semi-definite_matrices) that the complexity is cubic.

Furthermore, there it is said that it's more numerically stable than the [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition). And the LU decomposition is more stable than the method of finding all the eigenvalues.

And, it is a very elegant solution, because it's a fact:

A matrix has a [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) if and only if it is symmetric positive.

So why not using mathematics? Maybe some people are afraid of the raise of the exception, but it’s fact too, it's quite useful to program with exceptions.

Comment: From the same Wikipedia page, it seems like your statement is wrong.  The page says "
If the matrix A is Hermitian and positive semi-definite, then it still has a decomposition of the form A = LL* if the diagonal entries of L are allowed to be zero.[3]"  Thus a matrix with a Cholesky decomposition does not imply the matrix is symmetric positive definite since it could just be semi-definite.  Am I interpreting this wrong?  Also, it seems like you've just thrown "symmetric" across the implication.  i.e. shouldn't it be every Hermitian positive-definite matrix has unique Cholesky decomposition?

Comment: @user3731622 It is correct that Hermitian positive semi-definite matrices also have a Cholesky decomposition. But it is not a unique decomposition such as in the Hermitian positive definite case. So numpy decides to give you an error instead of randomly choosing one of possibly infinitely many decompositions to return.

Answer (score 4):

If you specifically want symmetric (hermitian, if complex) positive SEMI-definite matrices than the below will do. If you don't care about symmetry (hermitian, if complex) remove the 'if' state that checks for it. If you want positive definite rather than positive SEMI-definite than remove the regularization line (and change the value passed to 'np.lingalg.cholesky()' from 'regularized_X' to 'X'). The below

```
import numpy as np

def is_hermitian_positive_semidefinite(X):
    if X.shape[0] != X.shape[1]: # must be a square matrix
        return False

    if not np.all( X - X.H == 0 ): # must be a symmetric or hermitian matrix
        return False

    try: # Cholesky decomposition fails for matrices that are NOT positive definite.

        # But since the matrix may be positive SEMI-definite due to rank deficiency
        # we must regularize.
        regularized_X = X + np.eye(X.shape[0]) * 1e-14

        np.linalg.cholesky(regularized_X)
    except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
        return False

    return True
```

Comment: @DeepRazi Numpy's Cholesky decomposition implementation works on complex numbers (i.e. complex np.dtype). So yes it works in that sense. But my code above originally checked if the transpose rather than the conjugate-transpose is equal to itself which makes the overall function invalid for complex numbers. I have now change the transpose to conjugate-transpose and it is now valid for complex numbers.

Comment: `np.all( X - X.H == 0 )` is too strict; I think `np.allclose(X, X.H)` is better.

Comment: @syockit Well if you only care if a matrix is approximately Hermitian as opposed to actually Hermitian then yes. But to be clear, because we are subtracting elements of X from itself, there is no floating point or other numerical error in the calculation `X - X.H`. So if you are constructing X in a reliably Hermitian way then this algorithm is the way to go. If you are approximating a Hermitian matrix then I agree that using `allclose` is better.

Answer (score 2):

For a real matrix $A$, we have $x^TAx=\frac{1}{2}(x^T(A+A^T)x)$, and $A+A^T$ is symmetric real matrix. So $A$ is positive definite iff $A+A^T$ is positive definite, iff all the eigenvalues of $A+A^T$ are positive.

```
import numpy as np

def is_pos_def(A):
    M = np.matrix(A)
    return np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(M+M.transpose()) > 0)
```

Comment: This is the only answer properly answering the question by OP : "how to determine if a matrix is DP". All the other answers confusingly make the assumption that symmetry is needed for a matrix to be definite positive, which is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

For a nonsymmetric matrix, you can use the [principal minor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154018/principal-submatrix-and-principal-minor-of-a-matrix) test:

[image: This is a schema of what we learned in class]

```
def isPD(Y):
  row = X.shape [0]
  i = 0
  j = 0
  for i in range(row+1) :
    Step = Y[:i,:j]
    j+=1
    i+=1
    det = np.linalg.det(Step)
    if det > 0 :
        continue
    else :
        return ("Not Positive Definite, Test Principal minor failed")

  return ("Positive Definite")
```

Answer (score 2):

### Positive Definite

```
numpy.linalg.cholesky(x) # just handle the error LinAlgError
```

### Positive Semi-Definite

```
np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(x) >= 0)
```

*Notice: Most of cases  also `np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(x) > 0)` will give you if your matrix is `PSD` even if you see `>` and not only `>=`, I got into this problem some days ago. I figure it should be something about round off error due to the fact that we have really small eigenvalues and even cholesky decomposition might generate an error.*

### Note

In order to test, you might want to create some Positive semi-definite matrix and some positive definite matrices:

```
n_size=4
a = np.random.rand(n_size)
A_PSD = np.outer(a,a)  # the outer product of any vector generates a PSD matrix
A_PD = A_PSD+1e-5*np.identity(n_size) # little trick I found for PS matrix
```

Comment: To use `eigvals` to check for positive definiteness, you may need to compare to a certain epsilon. For example, `np.linalg.matrix_rank` uses machine epsilon multiplied by largest eigenvalue (and `max(x.shape)`), while `np.linalg.lstsq` uses machine epsilon in a similar manner. In fact, the above PSD test might fail if there is an eigenvalue below machine epsilon but with negative sign.

Comment: your comment is on point (I also notice a mistake in the code). when you are dealing with that situations, you are going to encounter the case you are talking about a lot, in my case is due to the tolerance rate of some solvers. most of the time, my work around is summing an identity matrix multiplied by a small value as in the last line of code in the answer, but this of course depends on your tolerance, in my case it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest this solution, valid for non-symmetric matrices. Basically it tries to find a non-zero vector ***z*** that minimizes the result of ***z***<sup>T</sup> · ***M*** · ***z***. As you see, it can either converge in a minimum (`minV['success']`) or reach the max number of iteration (`minV['status'] == 2`). If at this point the result is still positive, we could consider that the matrix is positive definite.

I guess there must be analytical methods to determine it, but I see a bit of confusion here about symmetric matrices (not a premise to be positive definite!!).

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def is_pos_def(m,z0='rand', maxiter=100):
    #tells if matrix is positive definite
    if m.shape[0] != m.shape[1]:
        raise Exception("Matrix is not square") 
    elif (m==m.T).all(): #symmetry testing
        return np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(m) > 0)
    else:
        def f(z):
            z=np.array(list(z))[:,np.newaxis]
            return np.dot(np.dot(z.T, m),z)
        if z0=='rand':
            z0 = list(np.random.rand(m.shape[0]))
        #constraints for a non-zero vector solution
        cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda z:  np.sum(np.abs(z))})
        minV = minimize(f, z0, method='COBYLA', options={'maxiter' : maxiter},constraints=cons);

        if minV['success'] or minV['status'] == 2:
            return minV['fun']+0 > 0 
        else:        
            return minV
```

This method works for both symmetric and non-symmetric, you can test with the following matrix ([checked with wolfram alpha too](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Is%20%7B%7B3%2C%200%2C%200%7D%2C%7B0%2C%202%2C%200%7D%2C%7B4%2C%203%2C%203%7D%7D%20positive%20definite%3F))

```
m=np.array([[3, 0, 0],
            [0, 2, 0],
            [4, 3, 3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

**Numerical inaccuracy is a problem when determining whether a matrix is positive/negative -definite or semi-definite.**

To illustrate this consider the following piece of code where I show that a positive-semi-definite matrix can look positive-definite or even indefinite due to numerical inaccuracy:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)


n = 5

A = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (n, n))
B = A @ A.T  # guaranteed to be positive-definite

w, v = np.linalg.eigh(B)
print(w)
# [0.00571615 0.29977027 0.44425488 2.67023429 3.82585751]

C = v @ np.diag(w) @ v.T
w = np.linalg.eigvalsh(C)
print(w)
# [0.00571615 0.29977027 0.44425488 2.67023429 3.82585751]
# Same as original!

w[0] = 0  # set smallest two eigen-values to zero
E = v @ np.diag(w) @ v.T
w = np.linalg.eigvalsh(E)
print(w)
# [4.06224137e-16 2.99770273e-01 4.44254883e-01 2.67023429e+00 3.82585751e+00]
#  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# Ooops! matrix is now positive-definite?!

w[:2] = 0  # set smallest two eigen-values to zero
E = v @ np.diag(w) @ v.T
w = np.linalg.eigvalsh(E)
print(w)
# [-5.14560681e-16  4.27158960e-17  4.44254883e-01  2.67023429e+00 3.82585751e+00]
#  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# Ooops! matrix is not definite?!
```

**The code above consists of the following steps:**

1. Construct a random matrix B which is guaranteed to be positive-definite.
2. Extract eigen-values/vectors, reconstruct matrix from these and extract eigen-values again to show that they coincide with the original eigen-values.
3. Make the smallest eigen-value zero, construct the resulting positive-semi-definite matrix, extract its eigen-values and show that it looks positive-definite.
4. Make the two smallest eigen-value zero, construct the resulting positive-semi-definite matrix, extract its eigen-values and show that it looks indefinite.

This example shows that even if the matrix is known to be positive-semi-definite we might not get any eigen-values which are exactly zero and we might even get very small negative eigen-values making the matrix look indefinite.

To overcome this issue we need to include a tolerance with which we will determine whether eigen-values are positive/negative/zero.

**Here is an example which shows that by using a tolerance we can correctly identify eigen-values that should have been zero and determine whether the matrix is positive/negative definite or semi-definite.:**

```
tol = np.finfo(float).eps

w_abs = np.abs(w)

is_zero = w_abs < w_abs.max() * tol
print(is_zero)
# [ True  True False False False]
#   ^^^^  ^^^^
# first two (smallest) eigen-values correctly identified as being zero

is_positive = w[~is_zero] > 0

s = 'the matrix is '
if is_positive.all():
    s += 'positive-'
elif not is_positive.any():
    s += 'negative-'
if is_zero.any():
    s += 'semi-'
s += 'definite'

print(s)
# the matrix is positive-semi-definite
```

Including a tolerance as in the example above primarily mitigates the issue of confusing a (semi-)definite matrix for an indefinite matrix, but there is still the issue that a definite matrix may well be misidentified as being semi-definite if some of the (strictly positive/negative) eigen-values are very small. I don't know of any robust solution for this and I suspect that it might just be an intrinsic limitation of finite precision arithmetic.

**I have written the following simple function which determines whether a matrix is positive/negative definite or semi-definite with a tolerance:**

```
def is_definite(x, sign=None, semi=None, tol=None):
    """
    Determine whether a matrix is positive/negative definite or semi-definite.

    Examples:

    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> np.random.seed(1234)

    >>> x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (5, 5)) + 1j * np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (5, 5))
    >>> is_definite(x)
    False

    >>> x = x @ x.conj().T  # x @ x.conj().T is guaranteed to be positive-definite
    >>> is_definite(x)
    True
    >>> is_definite(x, -1)
    False
    >>> is_definite(x, 1)
    True

    >>> w, v = np.linalg.eigh(x)
    >>> w[0] = 0
    >>> w
    array([0.        , 0.2272762 , 1.46465277, 4.61979679, 8.14691898])
    >>> x = v @ np.diag(w) @ v.conj().T
    >>> np.linalg.eigvalsh(x)
    array([-3.18173864e-16,  2.27276198e-01,  1.46465277e+00,  4.61979679e+00,  8.14691898e+00])
    >>> is_definite(x, 1)
    False
    >>> is_definite(x, -1)
    False
    >>> is_definite(x, 1, semi=True)
    True

    :param x: M*M-matrix or array of M*M-matrices
    :param sign:
            positive or negative number to check for positive or negative (semi-)definiteness respectively.
            Default is to return True for any definite matrix (positive or negative).
    :param semi: whether to check for semi-definiteness. Default is False
    :param tol: tolerance, default is machine precision
    :return: bool or array of bools
    """

    x = np.asarray(x)

    if x.ndim < 2:
        raise ValueError('x must be at least two-dimensional')

    x = (x + np.moveaxis(x, -1, -2).conj())/2

    if tol is None:
        tol = np.finfo(x.dtype).eps

    w = np.linalg.eigvalsh(x)
    w_abs = np.abs(w)
    is_zero = w_abs < w_abs.max(-1, keepdims=True) * tol

    if sign is None:
        pos = w > 0
        neg = w < 0
        if semi:
            pos |= is_zero
            neg |= is_zero
        else:
            pos &= ~is_zero
            neg &= ~is_zero
        return pos.all(-1) | neg.all(-1)

    ret = np.sign(w) == np.sign(sign)
    if semi:
        ret |= is_zero
    else:
        ret &= ~is_zero
    return ret.all(-1)


def is_positive_definite(x, tol=None):
    return is_definite(x, 1, False, tol)


def is_positive_semidefinite(x, tol=None):
    return is_definite(x, 1, True, tol)


def is_negative_definite(x, tol=None):
    return is_definite(x, -1, False, tol)


def is_negative_semidefinite(x, tol=None):
    return is_definite(x, -1, True, tol)


def is_indefinite(x, tol=None):
    return not is_definite(x, None, True, tol)
```