# Finding inverse of a matrix with high condition number

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, covariance, matrix-inverse

I am trying to find an inverse of [this 9x9 covariance matrix](http://pastebin.com/1agw0jTf) so I can use it with [mahalanobis distance](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis.html). However, the result I'm getting from [matrix inverse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html) is a matrix full of `1.02939420e+16`. I have been trying to find why, considering Wolfram would give me the correct answer, and this seems to have something to do with condition number of matrix, which in this case is `3.98290435292e+16`.

Although I would like to understand the math behind this, what I really need at this moment is just a solution to this problem so I can continue with implementation. Is there a way how to find an inverse of such matrix? Or is it somehow possible to find inverse covariance matrix directly from data instead?

**Edit:** Matrix data (same as the pastebin link)

```
[[ 0.46811097  0.15024959  0.01806486 -0.03029948 -0.12472314 -0.11952018 -0.14738093 -0.14655549 -0.06794621]
 [ 0.15024959  0.19338707  0.09046136  0.01293189 -0.05290348 -0.07200769 -0.09317139 -0.10125269 -0.12769464]
 [ 0.01806486  0.09046136  0.12575072  0.06507481 -0.00951239 -0.02944675 -0.05349869 -0.07496244 -0.13193147]
 [-0.03029948  0.01293189  0.06507481  0.12214787  0.04527352 -0.01478612 -0.02879678 -0.06006481 -0.1114809 ]
 [-0.12472314 -0.05290348 -0.00951239  0.04527352  0.164018    0.05474073 -0.01028871 -0.02695087 -0.03965366]
 [-0.11952018 -0.07200769 -0.02944675 -0.01478612  0.05474073  0.13397166  0.06839442  0.00403321 -0.02537928]
 [-0.14738093 -0.09317139 -0.05349869 -0.02879678 -0.01028871  0.06839442  0.14424203  0.0906558   0.02984426]
 [-0.14655549 -0.10125269 -0.07496244 -0.06006481 -0.02695087  0.00403321  0.0906558   0.17054466  0.14455264]
 [-0.06794621 -0.12769464 -0.13193147 -0.1114809  -0.03965366 -0.02537928  0.02984426  0.14455264  0.32968928]]
```

Comment: The link you provide do not necessary work for all due to firewall. Can you post your matrix IN the topic?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel edited the question to include data.

Comment: As such I provide my answer below which explain the big values, but going further it would be interesting to see what you want to achieve by trying to invert an unvertible matrix ...

Comment: I get a matrix with reasonable values when I run linalg.inv: http://pastebin.com/CHqxJqPV

Comment: if *covariance matrix* is uninvertible - you can use pseudo-inverse - [np.linalg.pinv](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html) - which "Calculates the generalized inverse of a matrix using its singular-value decomposition (SVD) and including all large singular values."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix `m` you provide has a determinant of `0` and is hence uninvertible from a numerical point of view (and this explain the great values you have which tends to bump to `Inf`):

```
In [218]: np.linalg.det(m)
Out[218]: 2.8479946613617788e-16
```

If you start doing linear algebra operations/problem solving, I strongly advise to check some basic concepts, which would avoid doing numerical mistakes/errors:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix

Comment: I'm actually aware of those basics, the problem is that I'm following an algorithm on Active Shape Model, which assumes that this matrix will be inversible. Therefore, I didn't expect that it would fail to meet this basic condition. The data is basically a sampled gradient from multiple images around one landmark point and I'm trying to build a statistical model for that point. The model - mean vector and covariance matrix is then used to find best match with other sampled vector by using mahalanobis distance. However, it fails at finding the inverse.

Comment: hum yes it is the model used which fails because of the matrix. You should take another approach in this case. But however it is good to automatically include a check on a determinant with a treshold when you have to invert a matrix. So that, if an error happens you can investigate more easily!

Answer (score 1):

calculate Covariance & do inverse [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813393/15893581)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import mahalanobis,euclidean
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

X = np.array([[ 0.46811097,  0.15024959,  0.01806486, -0.03029948, -0.12472314, -0.11952018, -0.14738093, -0.14655549, -0.06794621],
 [ 0.15024959 , 0.19338707, 0.09046136, 0.01293189, -0.05290348, -0.07200769, -0.09317139, -0.10125269, -0.12769464],
 [0.01806486, 0.09046136, 0.12575072, 0.06507481, -0.00951239, -0.02944675, -0.05349869, -0.07496244, -0.13193147],
 [-0.03029948, 0.01293189, 0.06507481, 0.12214787, 0.04527352, -0.01478612, -0.02879678, -0.06006481, -0.1114809 ],
 [-0.12472314, -0.05290348, -0.00951239, 0.04527352, 0.164018, 0.05474073, -0.01028871, -0.02695087, -0.03965366],
 [-0.11952018, -0.07200769, -0.02944675, -0.01478612, 0.05474073, 0.13397166, 0.06839442, 0.00403321, -0.02537928],
 [-0.14738093, -0.09317139, -0.05349869, -0.02879678, -0.01028871, 0.06839442, 0.14424203, 0.0906558, 0.02984426],
 [-0.14655549, -0.10125269, -0.07496244, -0.06006481, -0.02695087, 0.00403321, 0.0906558, 0.17054466, 0.14455264],
 [-0.06794621, -0.12769464, -0.13193147, -0.1114809, -0.03965366, -0.02537928, 0.02984426, 0.14455264, 0.32968928]])
    
cov = np.cov(X, rowvar=False)
covI = np.linalg.inv(cov)    
md = mahalanobis(X[0], X[1], covI)

# compare with PCA
##X -= X.mean(axis=0)[None, :]
pca = PCA(whiten=True)      # !! When True (False by default) the components_ vectors are multiplied by the square root of n_samples and then divided by the singular values to ensure uncorrelated outputs with unit component-wise variances.
X_transformed= pca.fit_transform(X)

print('Mahalanobis distance: '+str(md))
print('Euclidean distance: '+str(euclidean(X_transformed[0],X_transformed[1])))

## Mahalanobis distance: 4.094095146671607
## Euclidean distance: 3.999999999999999
```

or can use it with *Cholesky-decomposition* algo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41025851/15893581) and [math](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147210/efficient-fast-mahalanobis-distance-computation/147222#147222) OR  an alternative is to use the `cho_factor`, `cho_solve` functions, which is more efficient than computing an explicit inverse matrix. But Cholesky-decomposition can be applied only to square [positive definite](https://medium.com/sho-jp/linear-algebra-101-part-8-positive-definite-matrix-4b0b5acb7e9a#:%7E:text=Just%20calculate%20the%20quadratic%20form%20and%20check%20its%20positiveness.&text=If%20the%20quadratic%20form%20is,0%2C%20then%20it%27s%20negative%20definite.) matrix - [ensure this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266720/find-out-if-a-matrix-is-positive-definite-with-numpy) in its [quadratic form](https://github.com/weijie-chen/Linear-Algebra-With-Python/blob/master/Chapter%2017%20-%20Symmetric%20Matrices%20%2C%20Quadratic%20Form%20and%20Cholesky%20Decomposition.ipynb)

p.s. [mahalanobis distance vs. euclidean](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/9384), or
[2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166525/is-mahalanobis-distance-equivalent-to-the-euclidean-one-on-the-pca-rotated-data/166628#166628), or [3](https://waterprogramming.wordpress.com/tag/mahalanobis/):

> Squared Mahalanobis distances between the data points are exactly proportional to the weighted squared Euclidean distances computed on the principal components of the data. The weight being 1/eigenvalue of the component

I suppose there could be some mismatches due to the unstable manual inverse of the matrix.

p.p.s.
[PCA for image analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016059/pca-for-image-analysis-eigendecomposition-vs-svd?rq=1)... N.B. With SVD-Decomposition you can always check for the presence of *redundant params* (or inter-dependent features in LinRegr) - see [zero eigenvalues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16445/how-do-you-calculate-eigenvector-value-of-a-non-square-matrix-in-r) of S, to eliminate them (and eigenvectors associated with them) for MLR or, perhaps, use them somehow for your image analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You are faced with a very important and fundamental mathematical problem. If your method gives non-invertible matrix the method has a trouble. The method is trying to solve an [ill-posed problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem). Probably all well-posed problems have been solved in the XIX century. The most common way to solve ill-posed problems is [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_%28mathematics%29). Sometimes  [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) may be convenient. Scipy.linalg have pseudoinverse. But pseudoinverse is not a shortcut. Using pseudoinverse you're replacing non-solvable problem A by solvable problem B. Sometimes the solution of problem B can successfully work instead of non-existent solution of problem A, but it is a matter of mathematical research.

Answer (score 0):

Zero determinant means that your matrix has linearly dependent rows (or columns). In other words, some information in your model is redundant (it contains excessive or duplicate information). Re-develop your model in order to exclude redundancy.