# Calculate Rao's quadratic entropy

Tags: r, euclidean-distance, weighted

Rao QE is a weighted Euclidian distance matrix. I have the vectors for the elements of the d_ijs in a data table dt, one column per element (say there are x of them). p is the final column. nrow = S. The double sums are for the lower left (or upper right since it is symmetric) elements of the distance matrix. 
[image: Formula for Rao's QE]

If I only needed an unweighted distance matrix I could simply do dist() over the x columns. How do I weight the d_ijs by the product of p_i and p_j?

And example data set is at https://github.com/GeraldCNelson/nutmod/blob/master/RaoD_example.csv with the ps in the column called foodQ.ratio.

Comment: If you are looking for a Rao Quadratic Entropy function, you might try searching on "Rao" at this link: [link](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/search.html)

Comment: The csv file contains 56 rows (1 of which is headers) and 21 columns. If you convert to data.frame called df, drop the last column (which contains the p values) and run dist(df) R returns a distance matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still start with `dist` for the raw Euclidean distance matrix. Let it be `D`. As you will read from [R - How to get row & column subscripts of matched elements from a distance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39006382/4891738), a "dist" object is not a real matrix, but a 1D array. So first do `D <- as.matrix(D)` [or `D <- dist2mat(D)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51815064/4891738) to convert it to a complete matrix before the following.

Now, let `p` be the vector of weights, the **Rao's QE is just a quadratic form** `q'Dq / 2`:

```
c(crossprod(p, D %*% p)) / 2
```

Note, I am not doing everything in the most efficient way. I have performed a symmetric matrix-vector multiplication `D %*% p` using the full `D` rather than just its lower triangular part. However, R does not have a routine doing triangular matrix-vector multiplication. So I compute the full version than divide 2.

This doubles computation amount that is necessary; also, making `D` a full matrix doubles memory costs. But if your problem is small to medium size this is absolutely fine. For large problem, if you are R and C wizard, call BLAS routine [dtrmv](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d15/group__double__blas__level2_ga596c2acd9f81df6608bd5ed97e193897.html#ga596c2acd9f81df6608bd5ed97e193897) or even [dtpmv](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d15/group__double__blas__level2_ga1d9a8ecfddfea2c84e73e28e1ebb74cf.html#ga1d9a8ecfddfea2c84e73e28e1ebb74cf) for the triangular matrix-vector computation.

---

**Update**

I just found this simple paper: [Rao's quadratic entropy as a measure of functional diversity based on multiple traits](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.456.3162&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for definition and use of Rao's EQ. It mentions that we can replace Euclidean distance with Mahalanobis distance. In case we want to do this, use my code in [Mahalanobis distance of each pair of observations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41025851/4891738) for fast computation of Mahalanobis distance matrix.