# Mahalanobis distance not equal to Euclidean distance after PCA

Tags: python, pca, mahalanobis

I am trying to compute the Mahalanobis distance as the Euclidean distance after transformation with PCA, however, I do not get the same results. The following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import mahalanobis
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

X = [[1,2], [2,2], [3,3]]

mean = np.mean(X, axis=0)
cov = np.cov(X, rowvar=False)
covI = np.linalg.inv(cov)

maha = mahalanobis(X[0], mean, covI)
print(maha)

pca = PCA()

X_transformed = pca.fit_transform(X)

stdev = np.std(X_transformed, axis=0)
X_transformed /= stdev

print(np.linalg.norm(X_transformed[0]))
```

prints

```
1.1547005383792515
1.4142135623730945
```

To my understanding, the PCA uncorrelates the dimensions, and the division by the standard deviation weights every dimension equally, so the Euclidean distance should equal the Mahalanobis distance. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24221/mahalanobis-distance-via-pca-when-np), the relationship between PCA and the Mahalanobis distance only holds true with PCA components with unit variance. This can be obtained by applying PCA on the whitened data (more information [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit)).

Once you do that, the Mahalanobis distance in the original space is equal to the euclidean distance in the PCA space. You can see a demonstration of that in the code below:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import mahalanobis,euclidean
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

X = np.array([[1,2], [2,2], [3,3]])

cov = np.cov(X, rowvar=False)
covI = np.linalg.inv(cov)
mean=np.mean(X)
maha = mahalanobis(X[0], X[1], covI)

pca = PCA(whiten=True)
X_transformed= pca.fit_transform(X)

print('Mahalanobis distance: '+str(maha))
print('Euclidean distance: '+str(euclidean(X_transformed[0],X_transformed[1])))
```

The output gives:

```
Mahalanobis distance: 2.0
Euclidean distance: 2.0000000000000004
```

Comment: That works, thank you. Could you clarify why my division by the columnwise standard deviation (stdev = np.std(X_transformed, axis=0)
X_transformed /= stdev) does not satisfy "the relationship between PCA and the Mahalanobis distance only holds true with PCA components with unit variance"?

Comment: I am not sure I see how dividing the non-whitened PCA projected data by the standard deviation would help. My understanding is that the standardization of the data must occur before PCA is applied. There might be a way to transform the non-whitened PCA projected data to the whitened PCA projected data but off the top of my head I am not sure how to do that.