# Python function that takes matrices in as inputs, and identifies which ones are not positive-definite using np.linalg.cholesky

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

To check if a matrix is positive-definite (i.e. invertible), people often use `np.linalg.cholesky`, which returns the following error if a matrix is not positive-definite:

`LinAlgError: Matrix is not positive definite`

If the matrix is postive-definite on the other hand, the same function will output a numpy array.

Instead of just one matrix, I would like to check if several matrices are positive-definite using the `cholesky` function. I want to write a function that takes multiple matrices as inputs (A, B, C), feeds them sequentially into `cholesky`, and returns a statement saying

`"Matrices B and C are not positive definite"`.

I think it's hard to do because `cholesky` either returns an error, or returns an array as mentioned above. When it hits the error, the whole code being run is aborted, which is mainly what I want the function to be able to avoid/side-step. The function therefore must identify whether the output of `cholesky` *for each matrix* was an error, or was an array, and be able to identify all error matrices *by name* (A, B, C), while not being aborted by `cholesky`

Comment: Run matrices in a loop. Wrap the code in a try-catch, on failure catch the exception and log it. Then return successes and failures

Comment: could you expand or provide an example of catching exceptions and logging them? I have never wrapped a try-catch but would like to learn. When `cholesky` hits the error on its own, by the way, the whole script aborts, which is mainly what I want the function to avoid/side-step when evaluating the multiple matrices

Comment: Here's a scratchpad to get you started: [paste](https://pastebin.com/FD1RW1Li)

Comment: @cs95 Thanks. how to suppress the array that appears from `cholesky` upon a success?

Comment: Just don't append it to the dictionary on success?

Comment: not exactly, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266720/find-out-if-a-matrix-is-positive-definite-with-numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to determine whether a matrix is positive definite consists of catching the exception and then checking whether the exception is caused by the matrix being not positive definite. This function checks whether a matrix is positive definite:

```
import numpy as np
def matrix_is_positive_definite(m):
     try:
         ch = np.linalg.cholesky(m)
         return True
     except np.linalg.LinAlgError as e:
         if e.args[0] == 'Matrix is not positive definite':
             return False
         else:
             raise e
```

For a list of matrices as input, just apply the function to each matrix in the list using a loop or a list comprehension:

```
def matrices_are_positive_definite(l):
    return [matrix_is_positive_definite(m) for m in l]
```

If you want to print it in human-readable way, this is how you do it:

```
def print_not_positive_definite_matrices (l, names):
    not_positive_definite_matrices = [names[i] for i, m in enumerate(l) if not matrix_is_positive_definite(m)]
    if len(not_positive_definite_matrices) == 0:
        print('All matrices are positive definite')
    elif len(not_positive_definite_matrices) == 1:
        print('Matrix {} is not positive definite'.format(not_positive_definite_matrices[0]))
    else:
        print('Matrices {} and {} are not positive definite'.format(', '.join(not_positive_definite_matrices[:-1]),not_positive_definite_matrices[-1]))
```

Comment: thanks. when I add the line `matrices_are_positive_definite([A, B, C])` to my script, the script does not print the results, even though running the same line by itself afterwards without the script does print `[True,  True, False]`. How to make it always print?

Comment: @develarist That's probably because you are not printing the result. Are you working in a notebook? Notebooks will print the last value for each cell, that's why you're getting a a printed output when just calling `matrices_are_positive_definite(...)`

Comment: I'm running a larger script in spyder. could we include a `print` command in the function

Comment: Then you just need to print the returned value of `matrices_are_positive_definite`. "the function contains print regardles" you mean your function?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include how to print a human-readable result.